# If $a$ is rational and if $x$ is irrational, prove that $a + x$ is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

### Exercise

> If $a$ is rational and if $x$ is irrational, prove that $a + x$ is irrational.

---

### Attempt

Since $a$ is rational, we can express it as $\frac{m}{n}$.

Let us assume that $a + x$ is rational. Then, we can express it as $\frac{q}{p}$.

We then get $\frac{m}{n} + x = \frac{q}{p}$.

I would say that $x$ cannot be put over the same denominator as $m$, therefore the LHS cannot be expressed in a fraction and is hence irrational; but, that would be a lie because indeed $\frac{m}{n} + x = \frac{m + nx}{n}$.

---

### Request

I'm not sure on how to proceed. Hints, next steps, or full solutions are welcome.

Comment: notice that $x = (a+x) - a = \frac{...}{...}$...

Comment: This is easier than you think. if $a+x=q$ where $a$ and $q$ are rational, then $x=q-a$ is rational.

Comment: @JohnDouma -- Oh, wow. I expected something a whole lot more complicated. :) If you post it as an answer I'll mark it green.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a+x$ is rational, then $a+x - a = x$ is also rational, since the rationals are closed under subtraction:

If $\frac{r}{s}, \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\frac{r}{s} - \frac{p}{q} = \frac{rq-sp}{qs} \in \mathbb{Q}$ as well.

Comment: What does that reinforced Q mean?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is usually denoted for the set of all rational numbers, like $\mathbb{Z}$ stands for the integers, $\mathbb{N}$ for the natural numbers and $\mathbb{R}$ for the reals.

Comment: Al$\mathbb{R}$ight, thanks. :) I preferred @JohnDouma's comment, as it was more simplistic and elegant; however, I do like your's too. +1